# Managed Object Context and data fetch order

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

When I perform executeFetchRequest(NSFetchRequest) on the managed object context, does it always return the NSManagedObjects in the same order or not? What's the default return order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections in Core Data are always stored as unordered `(NS)Set` type for performance reasons.
If you need a specific order provide a sort descriptor in the fetch request.